# Selecting from a list of associations

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations

From a list of `Associations`

```
colors =
  {<|"key" -> 1, "c" -> Red, "op" -> 0.5|>,
   <|"key" -> 2, "c" -> Green, "op" -> 0.5|>,
   <|"key" -> 3, "c" -> Blue, "op" -> 0.5|>,
   <|"key" -> 4, "c" -> Yellow, "op" -> 0.6|>,
   <|"key" -> 2, "c" -> Green, "op" -> 0.8|>,
   <|"key" -> 6, "c" -> Gray, "op" -> 0.8|>};
```

I want to make the following selection:

```
GroupBy[colors, First] // Lookup[{2, 4}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Almost, but `GroupBy` has changed the sequence of the entries.

The only solution I found is quite flexible, but has to destroy and reassemble the data structure.

```
Map[Association] @ Cases[Normal @ colors, {___, ("key" -> 2 | 4), __}] // Dataset
```

[image]

```
Map[Association] @ Cases[Normal @ colors, {___, ("op" -> 0.5), ___}] // Dataset
```

[image]

**Question**

How can I get this functionality without having to leave the realm of `Associations`?

Comment: `Select[#op == 0.5 & ]`?

Comment: Yes! Or `Select[MatchQ[#key, 2 | 4] &]@colors // Dataset`

Comment: Or just leverage Dataset and queries: `colorsDataset[Select[MatchQ[#key, 2 | 4] &]]` where `colorsDataset = Dataset[colors]`

Comment: `ds = Dataset[colors]`; and `ds[Select[#key == 2 || #key == 4 &], All]` and `ds[Select[#op == 0.5 &], All]` .